# How do i port fql query to graph api

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-fql

As many of you might know FB is deprecating fql, so i have to port my fql queries to graph api.
But there's no info in the graph api docs covering the "how to make queries using graph api".
I have a fql query as follows:

```
SELECT message,attachment,created_time,message_tags,post_id from stream 
where source_id = me() and strpos(lower(message),lower('#site_update')) >=0
limit 10
```

How do i port this query to graph api request?
So far i'm stuck at

```
me/feed
```

So how do i add my query `strpos(lower(message),lower('#site_update')) >=0` to this request?
Also - there are no attachments in graph api. Why?!

**UPD:** They said on dev.facebook support "ask your questions on stackoverflow" - so? Where are the fb representatives to clear this out? We've got tons of apps working on fql.

Comment: Those functions aren't available afaik... So porting this to Graph API will give you a hard time. Parsing the results on the application side might be a remedy, but still not ideal.

Comment: No, no, parsing on the backend is not an option. Too slow. That's why i used fql. Don't know what to do now. Thank you facebook :D

Comment: Same here. Not clear to me why Facebook took this step without providing working alternatives. The whole Platform will be crippled starting May 1st 2015